# If $A^2=A$, $B^2=B$ and $I-(A+B)$ is invertible, then $R(A) = R(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $I-(A+B)$ is invertible and $A$ and $B$ are idempotent matrices, then how do I show that $A$ and $B$ have the same rank?

Comment: Use the rank formula and the decomposition of the space into eigenspaces for projections.